# What is the use of a callback in rethinkdb's run function

Tags: rethinkdb

I'm having trouble understanding why there needs to be a callback after a set of results have been returned (especially as any function can be put into the ReQL).Can someone give an example of how the callback can be used?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about the JavaScript driver.

The callback is just a normal node-style callback function into which the results are passed. You can use it instead of the promise, e.g.:

```
r.expr(5).run(conn, function(err, result) {
  if (err) { console.log("Error: " + err); }
  else { console.log("Result: " + result); }
});
```

instead of the promise-style version

```
r.expr(5).run(conn).then(function(result) {
  console.log("Result: " + result);
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log("Error: " + err);
});
```

I hope that helps. It normally doesn't make sense to use both promises and the callback.